# Как на qt написать двусвязный список?

Tags: qt, c++

Никак не могу понять как на qt написать двусвязный список. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: @машенька, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: А как односвязный сделать знаете?

Comment: В Qt есть готовая реализация списков QList. Но если вам надо самой написать двусвязный список, то мне кажется к Qt это не имеет никакого отношения.

Comment: я знаю как двусвязный список написать на с++, а вот с qt большие проблемы. и возможно ли импортировать код с++ в проект qt и чтобы он работал?

Comment: @машенька: Да, конечно. А какие проблемы? (Но это уже другой вопрос, задайте его отдельно.)

Comment: Доброго времени суток! А чем не подошел QLinkedList? http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qlinkedlist.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Принцип тот же, что и написать список на С++.

Выбираем проект в QT Creator и нажимаем "добавить новый..." (add new...)

[image]

Выбираем класс С++, то есть заголовочный файл + файл cpp;

[image]

Задаем имя для класса

[image]

Выбираем добавить проект в *.pro и завершаем создание класса.

[image]

Теперь у нас в проекте появились два новых файла с нашим новым классом, а так же они добавились в секции SOURCES и HEADER файла *.pro.

[image]

А дальше работа на созданием списка ни чем не отличается от того же в простом С++. Я взял простой пример, но вы скорее всего захотите создать список через шаблоны. Заполняем заголовочный файл.

[image]

Заполняем файл CPP:

[image]

Ну а дальше вызываем qmake и собираем проект:

- сборка -> запустить qmake
- сборка -> собрать все

Вот и все, должно работать.

---

Кстати, если у Вас уже есть готовый файл, то их можно просто добавить в проект как "добавить существующий файл" или вручную прописать пути в файл *.pro. Останется только добавить инструкции препроцессора #ifndef и #define на примере того, как это делает QT и вызвать qmake и собрать все.

[image]